# Is there a way to work with graphs in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures

I am building a bus ticketing application where I calculate the fare between stops with a graph like this

[image: Bus Fare Graph]

I am using PHP and MYSQL to build the application. Can someone tell me how I can store and work on this data since the number of columns and row can vary depending on the route.

Comment: please add your approach as well. So, that people can help you even further.

Answer (score 0):

You'd store the data like:

```
CREATE TABLE route (
  source integer unsigned NOT NULL,
  destination integer unsigned NOT NULL,
  fare integer unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (source, destination))
```

There's no column variance, only number of rows.

A fare lookup would be:

```
SELECT fare
FROM route
WHERE source = 1 AND destination = 2
```

Put numbers to cities in a separate lookup table.

Spreadsheets aren't the same as databases. They tend to show an output view rather than the important aspects of the data structure.